# How to calculate this weighted adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, network, adjacency-matrix

In "[Higher-order organization of complex networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08447.pdf)", network motifs is used to transform directed graph into weighted graph so that we can get symmetric adjacency matrix. [Here's how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXP6l.jpg).
There're [thirteen motifs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdMuM.png) with three nodes. I'm interested in to apply $\mathcal M_{4}$ and $\mathcal M_{13}$. For $\mathcal M_{4}$, matrix-based formulation of the weighted motif adjacency matrix $W_{\mathcal M_{4}}$ is $$W_{\mathcal M_{4}}=(B \cdot B)\odot B$$ 
where B is the adjacency matrix of the bidirectional links of unweighted graph $G$. Formally, $B=A\odot A^T$ where A is the adjcacency matrix of $G$. However, they didn't mention the calculation method for $\mathcal M_{13}$. The question is what should be the formulation of the weighted motif adjacency matrix of $\mathcal M_{13}$?

[This slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/arbenson/higherorder-spectral-graph-clustering-with-motifs) would be helpful to understand this paper.

[image: example graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a bit flip operation $\backsim$ that changes the $1$'s of a matrix to $0$'s and vice versa. There are several ways to define $\backsim A$ practically. One way is to subtract $A$ from a matrix filled with $1$'s. Another way to multiply $A$ by the square root of the appropriately sized identity matrix. We need to define another operation $*$ by $*A=[(\backsim A)\odot(\backsim A^T)]-I$ for the appropriately sized identity matrix $I$.

Then the formula you are looking for is given by

$$W_{\mathcal M_{13}}=(B\cdot B)\odot (*A)+(B\cdot (*A))\odot B+((*A)\cdot B)\odot B$$

The key to understanding this formula is to realize that the matrix operations act as logic gates such that $w_{ij}$ is only $1$ if there is a certain relationship between vertices $i$ and $j$.

Take $W_{\mathcal M_{4}}$ for example. An entry $w_{ij}$ in $(B\cdot B)$ is $1$ only if it is possible to reach vertex $j$ from vertex $i$ by taking a bidirectional edge followed by a bidirectional edge. And an entry in $(B\cdot B)\odot B$ is $1$ only if the previous condition is met and there is also a single bidirectional edge between $i$ and $j$.

Now the explanation for $W_{\mathcal M_{13}}$.
[image]

First, imagine we are dealing with vertices that have the same relationship as $a_1$ and $a_2$. This means the corresponding entry in $(B\cdot B)\odot(*A)$ should be $1$ since there is a bidirectional path of length $2$ between these vertices and they have no edge between them.

The second and third terms are cases if the vertices satisfy the same relationships as $b_1$ and $b_2$ or $c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively. The $+$ signs between the terms function as OR gates because within each motif each case only occurs once. On page $36$ of the article you posted, you might be wondering why for some motifs there's an additional step of adding the resulting matrix to it's own transpose. This is done for certain motifs that lack special symmetry, where $v_1$ compared to $v_2$ might not satisfy any of the cases, but $v_2$ compared to $v_1$ does.

In our case we don't have to worry about that because comparing $a_2$ to $a_1$ is the same as comparing $a_1$ to $a_2$. Comparing $b_2$ to $b_1$ is like comparing $c_1$ to $c_2$. And comparing $c_2$ to $c_1$ is like comparing $b_1$ to $b_2$.

Please let me know if any of this is confusing or doesn't make sense.

**Edit:**
I realize I originally made two big mistakes about $A$. I treated it like it was the adjacency matrix for an undirected graph and I didn't consider the fact that bit flipping $A$ would cause the diagonal entries to be $1$.

The idea behind the new operation $*$ is that $*A$ is the adjacency matrix of the complement of the graph described by $A$. The part $(\backsim A)\odot(\backsim A^T)$ acts as a NAND gate between $A$ and $A^T$ so that entries are $1$ only if the two vertices don't share an edge. We subtract $I$ to make sure the diagonal entries are $0$.

**Example**
The matrices for the three terms of the formula are 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
which sum up to 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I added the simple graph, could you show me the steps via example? I want to check if I could get it correctly.

Comment: @porttrum The steps of what specifically? Elaborating on the cases of the formula or actually going step by step through the transformation of a directed graph to a weighted one?

Comment: Now I totally understand. Thank you so much. I noticed by looking at the graph made from $W_{\mathcal M_{13}}$, if there is a path of $\mathcal M_{13}$ from vertex $u$ to vertex $v$, the direct path from $u$ to $v$ occurs.

Comment: I applied this method to [this graph](https://imgur.com/a/Cgf78f5), the $\mathcal{M_{13}}$ motif. And result of the obtained graph from its weighted adjacency matrix seems wrong. The definition of the $W_M$ is $(W_M)_{ij}=$number of motif instance in $M$ where $i$ and $j$ participate in the motif(on page 14). Is your method really correct? As I guessed from this definition, when $\mathcal M_{13}$ was applied to this graph, isn't it wrong to have a new edge?

Comment: You're right that for motifs $1$ through $7$ we would expect the weighted graph to not have any new edges. That's because vertices not connected by an edge can't possibly be related by those motifs. The same is not true for motifs $8$ through $13$. In general, if you apply a motif transform to the graph of the same motif, you will get that same triangle on the right side of that picture because clearly any two vertices in the motif are participating in the motif, and thus share an edge in the weighted graph.

Comment: Also slight nitpicking, in the picture on the right you don't need to draw the arrows. If vertices $i$ and $j$ participate in the motif then clearly the same relation holds for $j$ and $i$. If the motif transform ever gave you an edge that pointed in just one direction, then that would be evidence something has gone seriously wrong.